# Python Selenium webdriver ошибка при подключении к сайту USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors from и как спарсить изображения

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

В общем мне нужно спарсить диаграммы с сайта: https://hypercharts.co/aapl?frequency=annual и у меня возникли две проблемы, первая - при подключении к сайту вебдрайвер выдаёт ошибку:

[9000:8308:0719/133844.761:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors from ...

А вторая это то что при исследовании кода html сайта, я не обнаружил в коде ссылки на изображения диаграмм, а во вкладке network в xhr попадаются ответы без нужных данных, как я понял они юзают ajax или ещё что то наподобие. Так что если бы селениум и зашёл на сайт то возможно я бы не нашёл там изображений. Так что я не знаю пока что как спарсить диаграммы с этого сайта. Можете помочь пожалуйста с решением этих проблем?

Comment: Скорее всего отдельным запросом по ajax, посмотрел запросы и возможно это https://hypercharts.co/estimate?symbol=aapl . А так, вы можете через селениум загрузить и сделать скриншот элемент с диаграммой, для этого у элементов есть метод `screenshot` ([пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4c0a365eda89e411b181e24d5fffd6f4a450f1ac/selenium__examples/hello_world.py#L44))

Comment: Мне нужно подключаться к сайту где находятся эти изображение, а это просто json и даже при подключении к этому запросу у меня всё равно выходит эта ошибка